# HTML5 Audio Tag Stop Button, Stop a Live MP3 Stream?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, tags

I would like to add a stop button. At the moment only a play and pause button, but the stop is not really the browser bufferd the music, but does not jump to the beginning. With MP3 files is perhaps OK, but not in a live stream. Can someone help me? Thank you.

```
var pause = new Image();
pause.src = "pause.png";

var play_control = 0;
function playmusic() {
    if (play_control == 0) {
        document.getElementById('musikplayer').play();
        document.getElementById('playbutt').src = 'pause.png';
        play_control = 1;
        window.setTimeout("playcontrol()", 0); 
        window.setTimeout("zeitanzeige()", 0);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('musikplayer').pause();
        document.getElementById('playbutt').src = 'play.png';
        play_control = 0;
    }
}
function playcontrol() {
    if(play_control == 1) {
        if(
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').currentTime 
            == document.getElementById('musikplayer').duration
        ) {
            document.getElementById('playbutt').src = 'play.png';
            play_control = 0;
        } else {
            window.setTimeout("playcontrol()",0); 
        }
    }
}
function zeitanzeige() {
    if(play_control == 1) {
        var full = document.getElementById('musikplayer').duration;
        var full_min = Math.floor(full / 60);
        var full_sec = Math.floor(full - (full_min * 60));

        if(full_min < 10) {
            full_min = '0' + full_min;
        }
        if(full_sec < 10) {
            full_sec = '0' + full_sec;
        }

        var curr = document.getElementById('musikplayer').currentTime;
        var curr_min = Math.floor(curr / 60);
        var curr_sec = Math.floor(curr - (curr_min * 60));

        if(curr_min < 10) {
            curr_min = '0' + curr_min;
        }
        if(curr_sec < 10) {
            curr_sec = '0' + curr_sec;
        }

        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "" + curr_min + ":" 
                                                       + curr_sec + "";

        window.setTimeout("zeitanzeige()",0);
    } else {
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = "00:00";
    }
}
function vol(z) {
    switch(z) {
        case "1":
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').volume = 0.2;
            document.getElementById('vol1').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol2').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol3').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol4').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol5').style.background = '#8d8585';
            break;
        case "2":
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').volume = 0.4;    
            document.getElementById('vol1').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol2').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol3').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol4').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol5').style.background = '#8d8585';
            break;
        case "3":
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').volume = 0.6;
            document.getElementById('vol1').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol2').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol3').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol4').style.background = '#8d8585';
            document.getElementById('vol5').style.background = '#8d8585';
            break;
        case "4":
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').volume = 0.8;    
            document.getElementById('vol1').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol2').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol3').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol4').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol5').style.background = '#8d8585';
            break;
        case "5":
            document.getElementById('musikplayer').volume = 1.0;    
            document.getElementById('vol1').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol2').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol3').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol4').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            document.getElementById('vol5').style.background = '#c9c3c3';
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a stop button, there is no direct control through the javascript API for such a thing. But you can basically simulate the same behaviour by pausing the song and setting it to play from the start (providing you do not want to stop the buffering). Something like this:

```
var stop = function(stopButtonAudio) {
   stopButtonAudio.pause();
   stopButtonAudio.currentTime=0;
}
```

Comment: var stop = function (stopButtonAudio) {
                   stopButtonAudio.pause();
                   stopButtonAudio.currentTime=0;
     stop.src = "stop.png";
          }
        function stopButtonAudio() {
  document.getElementById('musikplayer').pause();
  document.getElementById('stopbutt').src = 'stop.png';

Comment: my function was a bit metacode, but you're supposed to have access to the currentTime property within the audio tag API: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp